# How to fix my warning in OrCAD?

Tags: orcad, eda, cadence, allegro

I'm doing a schematic on OrCAD and when I did the Design Rules Check I got a warning that says:

Checking Electrical Rules 
WARNING(ORCAP-1608): Net has no driving source N30274

I have a fairly large circuit that spans three pages, so is there any way that I could search for where the error happened? And what does this warning mean? I don't have any part called N30274.

Comment: Thank you guys for the tips and info. I searched for the net and found the two components that were connected together incorrectly. I had two inputs tied together :/ Also I didn't find it by searching from my top level design. I had to search each page individually. If the net that I searched for wasn't on the page then it would just return that 0 nets with that name were on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

N30274 is the name of the net connecting two parts.  If you go to your top level in the design explorer and do a search with that name you will find it.   Orcad auto generates net names for every wire connection you make.

Like Andy says it's trying to warn you that you have an input with no output, but it's probably not an issue.   If you edit the part in the library and right click on the pin I think you can see properties.   One will have a pull down for input, output, passive, etc.   if you set it to passive for both parts connected to that bet the warning will go away.

Personally I never use this feature and just set things to passive all the time, but it could be useful say to protect yourself from hooking up a serial port wrong.   It only makes sense if when you build all your library parts that you set the correct attribute for each pin.   Otherwise you'll always find warnings like this.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a design rule check there is a radio box you can tick that displays warnings directly on the circuit. They look like green circles.

This warning is trivial if in reality - it means that all devices sharing that common net are not designated as an output. Normally one is an output whilst the others are inputs or passive. This is set up in the part library editor but, like I say it's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the net is floating over. I have used Orcad long time ago and I couldn't find a clear solution. 
The net will be associated by the component names too. So you can easily identify which net is that. Check the netlist once again.